# Problem to convert Array of a string to ruby object

Tags: arrays, regex, ruby, type-conversion

I tried to pass array of string to use puts in ruby print it value with math operator. But get the wrong result. I thingk it need to convert to object to achieve this as follow.

```
my_string_array     =  ["100*(4+1)"]
my_string = my_string_array.join(' ') # => "100*(4+1)"
my_ruby_valuation = my_string.to_i # => 100 (Wrong)
```

What I expected is

```
puts my_ruby_valuation #=> 500
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute the code in the string? In that case, use `eval`, but there are security concerns to look for.

Comment: Yes, (thank for security issue but it's internal process for this one). It's work Would you move or add your comment in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use eval kernel function.
https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval

```
 my_string_array     =  ["100*(4+1)"]
 eval(my_string_array[0])
```

I hope this helps.